# How to chain multiple string value changes in a dataframe?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace

If the following is my dataframe

**Edit variable name**

```
forces2015 <- data.frame(Country = c("Russian Federation", "Egypt, Arab Rep.", "Iran, Islamic Rep."))
```

Now I want to change all individual values in one function but I can only think of this one:

**Edit column name:**

```
forces2015$Country <- gsub("Russian Federation", "Russia", forces2015$Country) 
forces2015$Country <- gsub("Egypt, Arab Rep.", "Egypt", forces2015$Country)  
forces2015$Country <- gsub("Iran, Islamic Rep.", "Iran", forces2015$Country)
```

I have maybe 10 of these values, so how do I solve this in the most elegant way possible?

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all()`

Comment: You can build a lookup table that maps one to the other and then use it to fill in the desired values.

Comment: Is the country field called Country or Country.Name?

Comment: Yeah sorry: country column is called Country and dataframe is called forces2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `recode` from `dplyr` package as follows:

```
forces2015$Country <- recode(forces2015$Country, "Russian Federation" = "Russia", "Egypt, Arab Rep." = "Egypt", "Iran, Islamic Rep." = "Iran")
```

Comment: Yeah thanks me neither. Works only with `tibbles` though, good to know.

Comment: I did not know about `recode()` either. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `qdap` package.

```
c1 <- c('Russian Federation', 'Egypt, Arab Rep.', 'Iran, Islamic Rep.')
c2 <- c('Russia', 'Egypt', 'Iran')

library(qdap)    
mgsub(c1,c2, forces2015$Country.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dplyr::case_when...

```
library(dplyr)

forces2015 %>%
  mutate(Country = case_when(
    Country == "Russian Federation" ~ "Russia",
    Country == "Egypt, Arab Rep." ~ "Egypt",
    Country == "Iran, Islamic Rep." ~ "Iran",
    TRUE ~ Country))
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Your code looks a little different when you copy my edits (editted after you answered) from my question.

Answer (score 0):

This way filters the data frame to relevant rows and quickly replaces the Country values. This good for a single replacement:
`data$Country[data$Country=="Russian Federation"] <- "Russia"`

If you want to replace many values using many conditions, while only using base library functions, I recommend using a series of `ifelse()` functions:

```
forces2015$Country <- with(forces2015,
                   ifelse(Country=="Russian Federation","Russia",
                      ifelse(Country=="Egypt, Arab Rep.","Egypt",
                         ifelse(Country=="Iran, Islamic Rep.","Iran",
                            Country))))
```